# Typed map does not support indexing

Tags: go, type-conversion

I want to extend [go-validator](https://github.com/go-validator/validator) to return a better type:

```
type Error map[string][]error

// Will output the first error when stringified (e.g. for json response).
func (err Error) Error() string {
    for k, errs := range err {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s value had %s", k, errs[0].Error())
    }

    return "no error"
}

func Validate(v interface{}) error {
    if ok, errs := DefaultValidator.Validate(v); !ok {
        return Error(errs)
    }

    return nil
}
```

As I am now writing tests for this I ran into the problem that it the typed map `Error` seems to have lost it indexing capabilities:

```
err = Validate(Value{
    Foo:      "bar",
    Email:    "foo@bar.me",
    Required: "1234",
})
c.Check(err, check.IsNil)

err, ok := Validate(Value{}).(Error)
c.Check(ok, check.Equals, true)
c.Check(err["Foo"], check.DeepEquals, []error{validator.ErrMin})
c.Check(err["Email"], check.DeepEquals, []error{validator.ErrInvalid})
c.Check(err["Required"], check.DeepEquals, []error{validator.ErrZeroValue})
```

Returns:

```
model/validation/validation_test.go:42: invalid operation: err["Foo"] (type error does not support indexing)
model/validation/validation_test.go:43: invalid operation: err["Email"] (type error does not support indexing)
model/validation/validation_test.go:44: invalid operation: err["Required"] (type error does not support indexing)
```

I also tried to cast to type `map[string][]error` but got "impossible type assertion".

**What is wrong with my approach?** **How can I get indexing back to work?**

Comment: Strange, considering this work: http://play.golang.org/p/J5oU0SFYVF

Comment: @VonC you think this is a bug?

Comment: It depends on the `c.Check` definition: can you share a link to the source of that `Check` method?

Comment: Here I rewrote it without anything: http://play.golang.org/p/JAbBMDLU9Z

Comment: c.Check comes from [gocheck](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/check.v1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your err variable is initialised with `error` type. When you do

```
err, ok := Validate(Value{}).(Error)
```

you merely check if err is actually an `Error`. If you change err there to say errs, it should work.

Playground example: http://play.golang.org/p/ljNroPzVbd

Comment: thank you! You were correct. I had defined `var err error` somewhere above and `:=` did not overwrite the var type...

Comment: You can't actually "overwrite" types in Go at all. You may store values of different types in interface variables, but they will still have a static type of interface. That is, a "struct" of two pointers, the first pointing to the value and the other to the type info. See [Russ Cox's article](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces) for more details.